# Django Admin: How to sort by data from another model?

Tags: python, django, orm, django-admin

I have the following two models in a [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/) app: `Event` and `EventDate`. I like to show some calculated data from *EventDate* in the admin list view of *Event* **and** I want to be able to sort by it.

I calculate the **next upcoming date** for each *Event* from the data in *EventDate*. Now I want it to not only show up in the [Django Admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/) list view for *Event* but I also want the events sorted by it.

The Django models look like this:

```
class EventDate(models.Model):

  date = models.DateField(db_index=True)
  start = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  end = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True)
  event = models.ForeignKey('Event')

class Event(TimeStampedModel):

  title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  text = models.TextField()
  published = models.BooleanField(default=False, db_index=True)
```

### What I tried so far

First I gave my *Event* model a **property** that returns the next date, which kinda works: I can show the next date in the `list_display` and even optimize with `prefetch_related`. **But** I can't sort on that field in the list display :(

Next I tried to add to the model with `extra`, to work around this limitation... Not that nice and forward but I came up with this:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

  def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(EventAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    qs.extra(
      select={
        'n2': """SELECT MIN(events_eventdate.date) FROM events_eventdate
          WHERE events_event.id == events_eventdate.event_id AND
          events_eventdate.date >= '{}'
          """.format(now().date().isoformat())
      }
    )
    return qs
```

It works in the debug shell but I can't get it to work in the admin. I have no clue on how to include it in `list_display` or what else to do.

Comment: Why didn't you put the foreign key in the Event model? Is it a weel-thought design or you just had to choose randomly between EventDate and Event? If the second option of my last question is true, you may consider putting the foreign key in Event, and it'd make everything easier

Comment: Also, see a link to that answer that may be helpful : http://stackoverflow.com/a/16073402/3768672. As well as this section of the doc : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#working-with-a-model-with-two-or-more-foreign-keys-to-the-same-parent-model

Comment: @RaphaelLaurent: An `Event` can have more than one `EventDate` (that's why I split the data to two models). If I get Django ORM right, that's the way to define a one to many relationship. Putting the FK on `Event` wouldn't work.

Comment: Indeed in this case, agree that your model is valid

Comment: @RaphaelLaurent: Thanks for the links. But I try to show the additional information in the list view for *Event*. Using *EventDate* inline worked fine. I try to add some more info to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I found a way to use the data from the extra call...

I added a method to the `EventAdmin` and set `admin_order_field` for that methode to the field generated by the extra call:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

  def get_queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(EventAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
    qs = qs.prefetch_related('eventdate_set')
    qs = qs.extra(
      select={
        'next_date': """SELECT MIN(events_eventdate.date)
          FROM events_eventdate
          WHERE events_event.id == events_eventdate.event_id AND
          events_eventdate.date >= '{}'
          """.format(now().date().isoformat())
      }
    )
    return qs

  def next_date(self, obj):
      try:
        return obj.next_date
      except IndexError:
        return 'abgelaufen'

  next_date.short_description = 'Nächster Termin'
  next_date.admin_order_field = 'next_date'
```

Not sure if this is clean or sane... it seems to work and I go for it, since it's pretty hard to get answers to Django Questions here. Will report if it bails on me.