# django: put related_name in admin - only as a list of links

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Seems like this'd be obvious - maybe it is... how can I put related_name into the admin?

If I have

```
class A(Model):
   whatever

class B(Model):
   a = ForeignKey(A, related_name='bs')
```

In the admin for B, 'a' shows up nicely. In the admin for A, how can I make the list 'bs' show up? I don't need to support inline editing, and the normal way of doing this (TabularInline) also shows more items in the 'bs' list than actually exist. Ideally, it would just show a list of hyperlinks to the relevant B objects...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to I show a list of ForeignKey reverse lookups in the DJango admin interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070809/how-to-i-show-a-list-of-foreignkey-reverse-lookups-in-the-django-admin-interface)

Comment: Do you mean how to show the list in the list display, or in the object view ?

Comment: Is the inline model method the only way? I'm gonna have to hack that a bunch to get what I want - just a list of hyperlinks to the relevant B objects, for only the B objects that exist in the set.

Comment: @karthikr: nope. In the admin page for some A model, I want to show the B models that this A is related to, and only them. Ideally, with no edit, but with each as a hyperlink to the admin page for the appropriate B.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  This is the main bugaboo with Django Admin that I've found.  Lists of hyperlinks in related object change views badly need to be a feature of Django.

Answer (score 1):

In edit and new object view, you can show related records with InlineModelAdmin objects https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

In list view you can define your custom column [Can "list_display" in a Django ModelAdmin display attributes of ForeignKey fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/163823/can-list-display-in-a-django-modeladmin-display-attributes-of-foreignkey-field)