# How to show list of hyperlinks to related objects in Django Admin detail view?

Tags: python, django-admin

In Django Admin I seem to always come up against the need for inlines with many entries...too many to be usable.  Relying on the model lists to create new entries loses the context, requiring extra steps by the user to associate the related models.  In other words, we lose the real convenience of doing it all on one page.

All I need is a scroll bar within the frameset that holds the inlines.  How to do that?

```
class ServiceHistoryInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ServiceHistory 
    extra = 0
    show_change_link = True
    can_delete = True
    fields = ['date','notes']

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        return qs.order_by('-date')
```

A compromise solution would be to set max_num= but still allow creation of a new entry, and an older entry would slide out of the frameset (with some indication that "there's more"), but you'd still be able to look up the older ones in the main model list page.

**UPDATE**:
Even better would be a dropdown list of hyperlinks to related objects, in other words links to the _set reversals of ForeignKeys.  This seems an obvious feature, why isn't it included or am I misunderstanding how it's meant to be implemented?  See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33400183/django-put-related-name-in-admin-only-as-a-list-of-links) from eight years ago.