# How to format OneToOne Relationship in Django Admin?

Tags: python, django, admin, models

I have 2 models that are connected via a OneToOneField Relationship. This is what they look like:

```
class UserText(models.Model):
    user_input = models.CharField(max_length=2000)

class Question(models.Model):
    user_text = models.OneToOneField(
        UserText,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    user_questions = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

I would like each UserText to have the Questions model connected to it within the database. This is why I used a OneToOne relationship. From here, I do not know how to represent this relationship within my admin.py so that when I look in my database through the admin I see each UserText model with its connected Question. This is what my admin.py look as of now:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from v2.models import UserText
from v2.models import Question

@admin.register(UserText)
class UserTextAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = UserText
    display = ('user_input')

@admin.register(Question)
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Question
    display = ('user_questions')
```

What do I need to add or change in my admin.py so that every Question model is connected to it's parent UserText model through the OneToOne relationship?

Comment: I believe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070809/how-to-i-show-a-list-of-foreignkey-reverse-lookups-in-the-django-admin-interface) may have a useful approach for you.

Comment: @Neelik This is pointing me in the right direction, thanks. I think I've got it from here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call the correct related field.

If you are inside the Question Admin Interface you need to add the `user_text`to your form:

```
@admin.register(Question)
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    fields = ('user_text', ...)
```

If you are inside the UserText Admin Interface you can use [inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects):

```
class QuestionInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Question

@admin.register(UserText)
class UserTextAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = [QuestionInline, ]
```

Btw, a `OneToOneField` is similar a `ForeignKey` with `unique=True`, in other words, each user can only have one question. If the user can have more than one question you should switch to a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: I have used the inline approach and it works like I wanted. I do want each UserText to have multiple questions related to it, will using a `ForeignKey` require any change in the inline admin code?

Comment: Okay, cool. So now I want to assign each individual question to one of the `OneToMany` question instances in the UserText Admin Interface. Right now, the admin shows multiple question fields `StackedInline` for each UserText, from here how do I add each question to each individual "Inline" field?

Comment: I think I didn't understand your question, but now for each question you need add an inline (ie, if the user has three questions, there should be three inlines). You just need to add a question inline and will be automatically associated with this user.

Comment: I think this is right. Would these inlines go inside the list you mentioned earlier: `inlines = [ QuestionInLine, ..., ..., ... ]`? And how exactly would I call them? Like what would I add after "QuestionInLine" in the list for each of these 3 hypothetical questions?

Comment: I'll make a separate question and link it to you so you can understand what I'm saying. It's hard to explain here in the comments

Comment: Yeah, I think it's better. I hope I can help again ;)

Comment: Sorry about my answer, but when I read it again, it seemed a bit confusing. What I wanted to say is that in Admin Interface you will see an inline for each question (not in your code). Ask a new question and I'll follow up.

Comment: Yeah, I think this thread will make more sense: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42351702/how-to-display-inline-objects-in-django-admin-interface