# How to delete products from inventory in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

**What I want:**
  I have the model classes named **Book** and **Issue**. In Book, there is a field named ***quantity*** that defines how many books are there. 
 When the Admin issue a book to a student, there will be a ***-1 in quantity***. how may I implement this.  
 N.B: I want to implement this in **Django Admin Dashboard**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

# Create your models here.

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    depertment_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    roll_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.depertment_name.upper() + ', ' + self.roll_number + ', ' + self.first_name.upper()


class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Issue(models.Model):
    issue_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    roll = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    book_name = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    issue_date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)


    def return_date(self):
        return datetime.now()+timedelta(days=3)

    def fine(self):
        return_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=3)
        if datetime.now() > return_date:
            return 'Fine'
        else:
            return 'No Fine'
```

**UPDATE: IMPLEMENTATION IS SOLVED. NEED TO SHOW RESULT**
please take a look here

[image]

**ADMIN.PY CODE**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from .models import User, Book, Issue

admin.site.site_header = 'Library Management System'

class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('roll_number', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'depertment_name')
    list_filter = ('depertment_name', 'semester')
    search_fields = ('roll_number', 'first_name')


class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'author_name', 'remaining', 'category')
    list_filter = ('category', 'author_name')
    search_fields = ('name', 'author_name')


class IssueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('issue_id', 'issue_date', 'return_date', 'fine', 'save')
    list_filter = ('issue_date',)
    search_fields = ('issue_id',)


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
admin.site.register(Issue, IssueAdmin)
admin.site.unregister(Group,)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, overriding **`save()`** method of `Issue` model would solve the problem,

```
class Issue(models.Model):
    # your code
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
            self.book_name.quantity -= 1
            self.book_name.save()
        else:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Update-1**
Inorder to get see the quantity of books, use **`book_name__quantity`** in `list_display` of `IssueAdmin`.

```
class IssueAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('issue_id', 'issue_date', 'return_date', 'fine', 'book_name__quantity')
    list_filter = ('issue_date',)
    search_fields = ('issue_id',)
```

Comment: Hello Jerin Peter George,
This solution is working perfectly. But the problem is the quantity of the books are not showing. can you please let me know how can I show the result in the admin dashboard.

Comment: What you mean by not showing? Can you add a screenshot or somrthing?

Comment: @Shojib Mahabub Add your `admin.py` file to the question

Comment: I have added admin.py code in the question and a screenshot of where I want to show the updated quantity.
currently, it is showing a dash ( - ) under the save column.

Comment: up[dated the answer, see **Update-1** section

Comment: Hi,
This is showing ERROR when I use book_name__quantity in list_display of IssueAdmin.
ERRORS:
<class 'app.admin.IssueAdmin'>: (admin.E108) The value of 'list_display[4]' refers to 'book_name__quantity', which is not a callable, an attribute of 'IssueAdmin', or an attribute or method on 'app.Issue'.

Comment: Pls look into this SO post. , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070809/how-to-i-show-a-list-of-foreignkey-reverse-lookups-in-the-django-admin-interface